# Stopwatch which runs faster than 15ms

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

Currently I have a timer which I assumed called the method defined in the `TimerCallback` field every 5ms, but after reading about the `Timer` class and it's resolution I discovered that the `Timer` class only has an resolution of 15ms or greater.

e.g.

```
autoDispatchTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(this.SendData), null, 0, 5);
```

I also looked into using a `Stopwatch` as this does allow for a higher resolution, but I am still unsure of how to use `Stopwatch` to carry out the same operation. Is there anyway this can be done using a `Stopwatch` object?

Would it be a a case of reading the `ElapsedMilliseconds` property and calling the `SendData` method there, or am I misunderstanding how the `Stopwatch` in C# work?

Help on this query would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I completely understand that the timer has an accuracy of 15ms, hence the rest of my question asking about an alternative which is faster. Title has now been modified to reflect this.

Comment: you can't have this, because system tyme accuracy is 15ms

Comment: I would suggest you look into Threading

Comment: Technically you could use `NtSetTimerResolution` to speed up the thread scheduling in windows, but I would advise against it. There's still no guarantees.

Comment: Time accuracy of 15ms is Windows 7: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @Pieter21: If it is okay to you: I included the link you posted in my answer.

Comment: Even if you could have this, it's unlikely that this is useful. What work are you going to start every 5ms (that is 200 times per second) that is observably different from doing three things every 15ms? SendData implies sending data over a network. The network jitter alone will mess up those ultra-precise timings.

Comment: I think you may headed in the wrong direction entirely. I've created a chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77788/stopwatch-which-runs-faster-than-15ms where we could continue the discussion on why this may or may not be useful, and what alternatives you have

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Timer` suspends in the background and at some point gets time to do something. That is guaranteed to be not faster than the time specified in your timer (so it will take *at least* the time specified, it can take more). I will usually take some milliseconds before it comes back. The [timer accuracy is 15ms on Windows 7 and higher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx), so there is no chance to get it faster like this.

The only thing that is faster than a `Timer` is a `while` loop. You could use that, or rethink your design (at least, that is what I would do).

Answer (score 1):

The timer resolution [documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/0/2/3027D574-C433-412A-A8B6-5E0A75D5B237/Timer-Resolution.docx) says:

> The system timer resolution determines
>   how frequently Windows performs two
>   main actions:
>
> - Update the timer tick
>     count if a full tick has elapsed.
> - Check whether a scheduled timer object
>     has expired.
>
> A timer tick is a notion of elapsed
>   time that Windows uses to track the
>   time of day and thread quantum times.
>   By default, the clock interrupt and
>   timer tick are the same, but Windows
>   or an application can change the clock
>   interrupt period.
>
> **The default timer
>   resolution on Windows 7 is 15.6
>   milliseconds (ms).** Some applications
>   reduce this to 1 ms, which reduces the
>   battery run time on mobile systems by
>   as much as 25 percent.

However you can try this:

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll", EntryPoint = "NtSetTimerResolution")]
public static extern void NtSetTimerResolution(uint DesiredResolution, bool SetResolution, ref uint CurrentResolution);

private void Foo()
{
    uint DesiredResolution = 9000;
    bool SetResolution= true;
    uint CurrentResolution = 0;

    NtSetTimerResolution(DesiredResolution, SetResolution, ref CurrentResolution);
}
```

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8aea13d9-35f1-4b66-a5b4-726651d985f7/how-to-set-timer-resolution-to-05ms-?forum=netfxtoolsdev)

You can also refer: [High-Performance Timer in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2635/High-Performance-Timer-in-C)

Comment: Better use documented APIs for that such as timeBeginPeriod.